# Prove a function is continuous on the union of closed sets if it is continuous on each set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I have a function $f: (A,d) \to (B,s)$ be a function between two metric spaces. If $$A=\bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$$ where $C_i$ are closed sets in $A$ and $f$ is continuous on each $C_i$.

Prove $f$ is continuous on $A$ and give an example where $f$ can fail to be continuous on all $A$ if instead I had a countably infinite union of closed sets $$A=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty }  C_i$$

So I take the open sets $O_i$ in $B$ then $f^{-1} (O_i)$ is continuous in $C_i$ so
$$f^{-1} \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n O_i \right)$$ gives me $$\bigcup_{i=1}^n f^{-1} (O_i)$$ which is open in $A$ as union of open sets.

Is this correct? I think I am missing something.

Also I wasn't able to find an example where $f$ can fail to be continuous on all $A$ if I had a countably infinite union of closed sets $$A=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty } $$
Can you give an example?

Comment: This is true if $\{C_i: i\}$ is locally finite (or more generally closure-preserving), otherwise counterexamples exist..

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you can only conclude that $f^{-1}(O_i)$ is open relative to $C_i$. It is an open set in a subspace instead of a "globally" open set.

The correct proof involves a variation of the definition: A function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed in $X$ for every closed set $F$ in $Y$. (You can try proving it by yourself. Almost one-line.)

Then for each closed set $F$ in $Y$, we have $$f^{-1}(F)=f^{-1}(F)\cap X=f^{-1}(F)\cap\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}{C_i}\right)=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}{\left(f^{-1}(F)\cap C_i\right)}.$$ Since $f$ is continuous on each $C_i$, it follows that $f^{-1}(F)\cap C_i$ is closed in $C_i$ and even in $X$ (because $C_i$ is closed!!). Note that here we have a finite union of closed sets, so $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed. By the theorem we mentioned above, $f$ is continuous.

As for the counterexample, I think you have realized the point: countable union of closed sets is not necessarily closed. Try to find one by yourself!

Comment: Can you explain why we have$ f^{-1} (F)=\bigcup_{i=1}^n  f^{-1} (F \cap C_i)$, $F$ is in $Y$ and $C_i$ is in $X$ , they lie in different sets, what does it mean to take their intersection?

Comment: No. I wrote $f^{-1}(F)\cap C_i$. Both are subsets of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

In a metric space $X,$ every singleton (i.e. $\{x\}$ for $x\in X$) is closed, and any function with domain $\{x\}$ is continuous. Suppose $A=B=\{1/n:n\in \Bbb N\}\cup \{0\}$ with $d(u,v)=s(u,v)=|u-v|.$ Let $C_1=\{0\}$ and $C_j=\{1/(j-1)\}$ for $j>1.$ Let $f:A\to B$ be discontinuous at $0.$ E.g. $f(1/n)=0$ and $f(0)=1.$